# mod-rewrite rule - How do I cut a URL after the characters ":"

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to clean up my URLs with the help of `modrewrite`.
So that google can read them better.

so the URLs looks now:
**domain.com/article:::451.html**

so it should look like:
**domain.com/article**

I never work otherwise with modrewrite. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect :

**domain.com/article:::451.html**

to

**domain.com/article**

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article:::451\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article [L,R]
```

If the old uri is dyanamic, eg: (/foo:::1234.html), you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^:]+):::[0-9]+\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```